# supplied XML is not in well format while passing XML

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, soapui

I am getting below error while passing xml.Supplied XML is not in well format.
I have checked my xml in xml validator there is no any issue please suggest what can be the scenario

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MANd.png)

<responsexml><response>The supplied XML is not in well form</response></responsexml>

[XML input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79fD9.png)

Comment: Seems like you need to change > to &lt;, that seems an issue in image you have attached.

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: What's the content of your request message?

Comment: @craigcaulfield find the xml input file

Comment: @RedBoy I tried changing that it doesnt work please suggest

Comment: Yep, the request looks well-formed. The only other thing that looks unusual is that response message "The supplied XML is not in well form". That doesn't look like a standard parsing error message. Do you have access the server-side code that is processing your request? There may be custom validation happening that eventually throws back the error you're seeing. And, for future reference, post the text of any code/XML/JSON rather than images. It makes it easier to search and reproduce your problems.

Comment: @craigcaulfield yup thanks for your response i will check the access for server side

Comment: The other option is to wrap the response in `CDATA`  like this  `<![CDATA[response xml]]>`

Comment: @RedBoy thanks for that i tried that but it is not working